# why do unary operators return different type than their operands?

Tags: c++, return-type, unsigned, unary-operator

It looks as if the unary bitwise not operator (~) on uint16_t and uint8_t returns int,
and not the type of its operand (same for unary -).
Can someone give a reason why this is so?

It came as a surprise that ~uint16_t(0) < uint16_t(0)

I use g++ version 9.2.1 20191008 (Ubuntu 9.2.1-9ubuntu2) x86_64-linux-gnu

Comment: Because the "usual promotions" are always performed on all operands. The ~ operator only works on operands of type int, long, long long, unsigned, unsigned long, and unsigned long long. Everything else needs conversion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From C++11 [Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) 5.3.1.8:

> The operand of the unary - operator shall have arithmetic or unscoped enumeration type and the result is the negation of its operand. Integral promotion is performed on integral or enumeration operands. The negative of an unsigned quantity is computed by subtracting its value from 2^n, where n is the number of bits in the promoted operand. The type of the result is the type of the promoted operand.

So it states that integer promotion takes place for unary operators.

Comment: Any thoughts of why they came up with that?

Comment: (My personal thoughts. Not pretend to be true.) Modern hardware operates with registers which usually are fixed width, e.g. 64 bit. To keep language efficient it makes sense to promote everything to register width. Imagine how complex would be hardware if you have to handle only part of the register.

Comment: That makes sense. And I guess that registers prefer signed values.