# Why does gcc expand int16_t to int32_t on unary minus operator?

Tags: gcc

In the following example, gcc produces an `int32_t` for the expression `(-i)`. Even if I change the expression to `(zero-i)` (with `static constexpr int16_t zero = 0`), the expression remains a 4-byte `int32_t`. What is the logic here?

```
#include <iostream>                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                         
int                                                                                                                                      
main()                                                                                                                                   
{                                                                                                                                        
    int16_t i = 4;                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                         
    std::cout << "sizeof(i): " << sizeof(i) << std::endl;                                                                                
    std::cout << "sizeof(-i): " << sizeof(-i) << std::endl;                                                                              
                                                                                                                                         
    return 0;                                                                                                                            
}
```

Expected:

```
sizeof(i): 2
sizeof(-i): 2
```

but got:

```
sizeof(i): 2
sizeof(-i): 4
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why do unary operators return different type than their operands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60587449/why-do-unary-operators-return-different-type-than-their-operands)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the logic here?

The logic is in the C++ standard (e.g. C++11 5.3.1:7) (C standards has equivalent clauses):

```
The operand of the unary - operator shall have arithmetic or unscoped
enumeration type and the result is the negation of its operand.
Integral promotion is performed on integral or enumeration operands
```

and 4.5:1

```
A prvalue of an integer type other than bool, char16_t, char32_t, or
wchar_t whose integer conversion rank (4.13) is less than the rank of
int can be converted to a prvalue of type int if int can represent all
the values of the source type; otherwise, the source prvalue can be
converted to a prvalue of type unsigned int.
```

According to the above `i` is promoted to `int` before unary minus is applied to it and the result of `-i` expression is also `int`.